# how to take the difference of two observable arrays?

Tags: knockout.js

I have two observable arrays which can have matching items. I would like two filter these two arrays and find the unique items. the duplicate items can be matched on the ID attribute.

is there a way to accomplish this without having to create nested loops, I am concerned in regards to the impact this approach will have on the performance of the page.

currently I am doing it the following way, if you know of a better way please feel free to share.

```
self.alerts = ko.computed(function () {
    var duplicates = [];
    var alerts = ko.mapping.fromJS(ko.toJS(Neptune.SonarAlerts.alerts()));
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.selectedAlerts(), function(selected) {
        var duplicate = ko.utils.arrayFirst(alerts(), function(item) {
            return selected.ID() == item.ID();
        });

        if (duplicate != null) {
            duplicates.push(duplicate);
        }
    });

    alerts.removeAll(duplicates);

    return alerts();
});
```

Comment: Intersect?.....but it's all just loops at some level....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some level, loops are going to be implemented,  but if you have underscore.js, you can at least do this in a functional way with its [intersection](http://underscorejs.org/#intersection) method:

`var matchingItems = _.intersection(array1, array2);`